# Query working on LINQPad but running on VS returns a NullReference error

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

My query is this:

```
var query = from a in tableA
join b in tableB
on tableA.ID
equals tableB.ID
join c in tableC
on tableA.ID
equals tableC.ID
where a.ID == "0001"
&& (from d in tableD
     where
     d.Flag == "1" &&
     d.Address == c.Address
   ).Any()
select new
{
    a.Name,
    b.Price,
    c.Address
}
```

When I remove the condition with the .Any() function, it runs fine. Why is the VS returning an error when LINQPad runs fine as is? Running also the raw SQL equivalent which is EXISTS, if I'm not mistaken runs fine and gives the correct results. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show us more information/details about exception?

Comment: The error is:

NullReference error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Your VS code has a context defined and opened in the query correct? example snippet: `var query = from a in context.tableA ...`